Problem with html and css code when opened with mobile
I was coding the home page of my new project without thinking about how could it be on a vertical device. now i just finished with the page and i tried to see it with different devices on the chrome inspect and it is just not good. my question is, i am pretty new with the whole web desining world, should i change just the mobile css with @media.... or should i start over the whole css?
I will leave my code.
Any tip or suggestion is welcomed, thanks.
Edit: thanks to everyone, i'll add the media query, in order to not start over, but I noticed an other error.
My nav-bar at the bottom of the page can't be clicked due to the .title-2 that occupies the whole line, even though there is no padding, in fact the .title-1 is perfect, any suggestion?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="section" id="pablitoshotit">
            <div class="home-container">
                <div class="home-background" style="background-image: url('imgs/home-type-3-1.JPG');"></div>
                <div class="home-content">
                    <p class="contacts"><a class="contacts-link" href="#contacts">CONTACTS</a></p>
                    <h1 class="titolo" id="titolo-1">
                        PABLITO
                    </h1>
                    <h1 class="titolo" id="titolo-2">SHOT IT</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="hero">
                    <nav>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#streetphotography">STREET PH</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#artists">ARTISTS</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#rideout">RIDE OUT</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#live">LIVE</a></li>
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <script src="home.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

html, body{
    overflow: hidden;
}

body{
    background-color: black;
}

.home-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.home-background{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;
}

.home-content{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15%;
}

.contacts{
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
}

.contacts-link{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.titolo{
    font-size: 100px;
    letter-spacing: 15px;
    color: #fff;
}

#titolo-1{
    margin-left: -800px;
    margin-top: -150px;
}

#titolo-2{
    margin-right: -800px;
    margin-top: -250px;
}


.hero{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(12,3,51,0.3),rgba(12,3,51,0.3));
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 5%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 0;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 8%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: -500px;
    margin-left: -200px;
}

nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-flex;
}

nav ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (){
    const images = ['imgs/home-type-3-1.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-2.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-3.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-4.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-5.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-6.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-7.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-8.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-9.jpg', 'imgs/home-type-3-10.jpg'];
    const homebackground = document.querySelector('.home-background');
    let index = 1;

    const imageObjects = [];
    images.forEach(function(imageSrc) {
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = imageSrc;
        imageObjects.push(img);
    });

    function changeBackground(){
        homebackground.style.backgroundImage =  `url('${images[index]}')`;
        index = (index+1) % images.length;
    }

    setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
});


research and learn "Responsive design" - you may well need to rewrite most of the CSS - or maybe not - depends on what you want your website to look like on various devices, which is a matter of opinion

First read how to do Responsive Design. Than decide what does it mean to be it is just not good and fix it

You should stop using absolute positioning and negative margins.

You can start by adding media query. you need not to start over the whole css.
try to fix screen on mobile first , add css properties needed on large screens (Laptop and Desktops) inside the following media query.
@media (min-width: 992px) {
   //add css for large screens here
}

css for medium screens (tabs and others) add inside the following media query
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
 //add css for medium screens here
 }


You can start adding breakpoints for standard resolutions (mobile, tablet and web) and adjust the styles for each resolution.
The code may end up a little dirty, but as long as it works, practice will make you improve.
